# Which clang tool catches out of range iterators?

Tags: c++, clang

MSVC catches the error in line 7 in the following code.  Specifically, `remove_copy()` on line 9 copies into a string which isn't large enough.  When debugging in MSVC, the error is **Expression: cannot dereference string iterator because it is out of range (e.g. an end iterator)**. When using Clang-8, I get no error.

How can I catch this error using Clang on either Windows or Linux?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::string source{ "foo-bar-baz" };
    std::string dest; // PROBLEM

    auto last = std::remove_copy(begin(source), end(source), begin(dest), '-');
    dest.erase(last, end(dest));

    std::cout << source << "\n"; // "foo-bar-baz"
    std::cout << dest << "\n"; // expected: "foobarbaz"
}
```

Comment: Does this help: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer.html   ?

Comment: @RichardCritten Yes, perhaps.  I can't get it to catch the error though.